# Output of |git show patch| viewable using the visual difftool?

Tags: git

This seems like straightforward ask but I can't find an invocation. As the title suggests, I want to type:

`git show -p <commit>`

and see the results in my visual diff tool, rather than diff.  Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use a visual diff tool with `git show`.

`man git-show` reads:

> For commits it shows the log message and **textual** diff. It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree --cc.

Unfortunately, no mention of visual tools.

So the only tools that can use visual diff tools are `difftool` and `mergetool`.

You can use your difftool to view the contents of an arbitrary commit with `git difftool <commit>^ <commit>`. Though you won't see the commit message.